# Get width of terminal in Node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal

```
console.log(process.env.COLUMNS)
```

Yields `undefined`, although,

```
$ echo $COLUMNS
```

Outputs as expected:

```
78
```

I have been trying running Node like this `env node myprog.js`, still `undefined`. What's wrong with me or any other way to know the width of terminal? (For nice formatting of some output data).

Comment: When I tried `console.log(process.env)` outputs the same as `printenv` and for some reason $COLUMNS is not on `printenv`output.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
console.log('Terminal size: ' + process.stdout.columns + 'x' + process.stdout.rows);
```

And the output looks like e.g. "Terminal size: 80x24". There is also an event if the console size changes.

It's explained under [tty](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html) in the docs.

Comment: I believe, it should be used as `(process.stdout.columns || defaultColumns)` because the `stdout.columns` could be `undefined`.

Comment: "-".repeat(process.stdout.columns) to create a line across the terminal.

Comment: `"-".repeat(process.stdout.columns - 2)` to account for the beginning ' and ending ' characters ^_^

Comment: Please NOTE @SlavaFominII's remark ! I have had code fail in production because process.stdout.columns was undefined in a container.

Comment: @SlavaFominII What is `defaultColumns` here? Is it some provided property, or a value you set to whatever you want?

Comment: @user3932000 no, you can set it as you wish