# How to monitor for console size change in nodejs

Tags: node.js, terminal, console

How do you get notified when somebody resizes the associated terminal windows in nodejs, for to re-draw TUI stuff?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335637/get-width-of-terminal-in-node-js?

Comment: I want to create a TUI application which dynamically responds to resizes of the terminal, like e.g. some installers or cfdisk does. For this it's not enough just to read the current size as I'd have to poll this value continuously which creates an unacceptable overhead. There must be some other way to do this.

Comment: You want to detect SIGWINCH. In linux you can use ncurses

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to detect SIGWINCH.

See the docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!